# Установить относительный путь к директории Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, path

Добрый день!

Нужно прописать путь до папки с файлами. В папке находятся картинки и их нужно будет фильтровать.

Когда прописываю полный путь программа работает.

```
File selectedDirectory = new File("C:\\Studentbook\\src\\sample\\img\\page1");
```

Пытаюсь прописать относительный пишет ошибку. Относительный путь нужен для того, чтоб программа работала на разных компьютерах.

Нужно `File selectedDirectory = new File("../img/page1");`

```
    File selectedDirectory = new File("page1/");

    FilenameFilter filterJpg = new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".png");
            }
        };

        filesJpg = selectedDirectory.listFiles(filterJpg);
```

Answer (score 1):

Пусть в корневой папке проекта есть папка `img`.

Доступ к этой папке можно получить, например, таким образом:

```
File directory = new File("img/");
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я попробовал ваш метод, к сожалению не получилось. Может быть я скину код и станет яснее.

Comment: File selectedDirectory = new File("page1/");

        FilenameFilter filterJpg = new FilenameFilter() {
                public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                    return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".png");
                }
            };

            filesJpg = selectedDirectory.listFiles(filterJpg);

Comment: Вы этот код добавьте в свое первоначальное сообщение. И еще, Вы проект из IDE запускаете? Или как?

Comment: Да, я использую IDEA.

Comment: Что выводится при `System.out.println(new File("").getAbsoluteFile());`?

Comment: C:\Studentbook\page1

Comment: Хотя путь немного другой... Я понял свою проблему, но как решить все равно не представляю.

Comment: В таком случае папка `img` должно быть дочерней для той папки, путь к которой Вы получили выше. Тогда `File directory = new File("img/");` сработает корректно.

Comment: Так Вы сформулируйте эту проблему :)

Comment: Я не верно указал путь

Comment: С:\Studentbook\
А путь к папке С:\Studentbook\src\sample\img\page1
В данном отезке кода, программа загружает картинки и фильтрует. В итоге даные я использую в двух местах. int numOfPage = filesJpg.length; для определения количества изображений и 

  pagination = new Pagination(numOfPage);
        pagination.setPageFactory(new Callback<Integer, Node>() {
            @Override
            public Node call(Integer pageIndex) {
                return createPage(pageIndex);
            }
        });

для создания SlideShow

Comment: Вы лучше такой код в комментарии не помещайте – нечитаемо. Лучше четко сформулируйте свою проблему: что хотите сделать, что делаете и что не получается. И все это в виде нового вопроса сделайте.